Default argument evaluation of __dirname with NextJS builds
I have the following React component:
export async function Index({ base = (() => __dirname)() }: IndexProps) {
  const sanitizedBase = sanitizeBasedir(base);
  const subPages = await listPages(sanitizedBase, ".", 1);
  return (
    <div>
      <ol>
        {subPages.map((subPage, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <a href={subPage.relativePath}>{subPage.title}</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
}

I use this component on the page.tsx of each route to list the subpages of that route "dynamically".
export default async function Page() {
  return <Index />;
}

This is used by several routes in my app, such as app/route1, app/route2, app/route3 etc. The problem is that when I run next build, the generated website will randomly list the subpages of routeN as the subpages of routeM (N!=M). The results are shuffled. It looks like __dirname is evaluated with the invoker modules context but not in a predictable way.
Is there a way to make this deterministic without having to explicitly pass __dirname (or equivalent) as a prop every time the Index component is used? I've confirmed doing so does the trick, but it would be nice to keep it DRY.
UPDATE 1: I've tried to use stack traces to investigate the call stack a bit and it looks like the __dirname is wonky due to NextJS being too clever and probably shuffling things around when rendering components. With these changes:
function revealStackTrace() {
  throw new Error();
  return "";
}

export async function Index({ base = revealStackTrace() }: IndexProps) {
  ...
}

during next build I see:
Error occurred prerendering page "/routeN". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Error
    at /.../.next/server/app/(routeGroup)/routeM/page.js:1:5604
    at h (/.../.next/server/app/(routeGroup)/routeM/page.js:1:5612)
    at eh (/.../node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:134657)

So there's probably nothing I can do in terms of NodeJS to get the dirname right at component rendering time, unless there's some NextJS configuration I can use to "dumb it down".

Why do you need to use __dirname here? Typically, __dirname is determined on run time when your app is already bundled. If you want to access the relative path of the current file, you can try to expose __fillename from the webpack config

Exposing __filename via web pack might do the trick, I'll give it a try!

I think the issue is how nextjs handles the server side rendering and the build process. In production, nextjs optimizes and bundles routes which can lead to sharing modules across different pages. This can cause error to occur when trying to do __dirname cuz it behaves unpredictably cuz of module bundling. Also, bundling might combine multiple components into same file.
You can do something like this:


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { resolvedUrl } = context;
  return { props: { basePath: resolvedUrl } };
}

export default function Page({ basePath }) {
  return <Index base={basePath} />;
}



But you will have to do this for each route. It might work for you but if it doesn't work then,
Create environment variable. For eg: create .env file and set a variable BASE_DIR=your/dir/path
and do process.env.BASE_DIR to get the path to your project.

Yeah doing this for each route is a no-go, the goal of using __dirname was so I could do this once for all routes. An environment variable is less worse but I'd need more than one if I have more than one base.
